# Highlight entirerow if it contains date less than yesterday, excluding weekends

Tags: excel, vba

I have data with column G as dates, I need to highlight entire row if the date is less the yesterday and skip if weekend. I tried the below however all my data is getting highlighted for yesterday as well.

```
For each cell in Range("G2":G & endrows)

    If cell.Value < Format(Application.Worksheetfunction.Workday(Date, -2)"dd.mm.yyy" Then
    cell.Entirerow.Font.color = rbg.red

Next Cell
```

This is not working on my data it is highlighting all the rows even if it contains yesterdays date.
However I need it to only highlight less than yesterday. And if it is a Monday, calculate yesterday as Friday and not Sunday.

Comment: You have More than one condition so you need to use "WorksheetFunction.CountIfs" like
For Each cell In Range("G2:G " & endrows)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(cell, "your condition2 ", cell, "condition2") > 1 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Font.Color = rbg.red
Next cell

Comment: You know, don't you, that you can click green the tickmark beside the answer if it works for you (or if several answers, the one that you consider the best). Later when you earn enough "reputation" you can also upvote any answer (not only answers to your questions) that is helpful for you. You can read more about it in [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next updated code. In order to make the code faster, it will use a `Union` range (`rngH`), to color the necessary rows font at once, at the end:

```
Sub highliteRowsDateBased()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, endRows As Long, i As Long, rngH As Range, cel As Range
  Const firstWeekDay As Long = vbMonday 'adapt it according to your real first day
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  endRows = sh.Range("G" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  For Each cel In Range("G2:G" & endRows)
    If cel.Value < (Date - 1) And Weekday(cel.Value, firstWeekDay) <= IIf(firstWeekDay = vbMonday, 5, 6) _
                             And Weekday(cel.Value, firstWeekDay) > IIf(firstWeekDay = vbMonday, 0, 1) Then
        If rngH Is Nothing Then
            Set rngH = cel
        Else
            Set rngH = Union(rngH, cel)
        End If
    End If
 Next cel
 If Not rngH Is Nothing Then rngH.EntireRow.Font.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

In your code `Range("G2":G & endrows)` is a wrong VBA construction. It should be `Range("G2:G" & endrows)`.

Coloring each row at a time makes the code slow.

If the week, according to your regional settings does not start on Monday,  please, adapt `firstWeekDay` constant.

Comment: @Shivani Kamthe Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the left code side check box, in order to make  it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works...

Comment: Apologies, I am new to this website. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I have tested this coding and realized that it is working fine on all days but not on a Monday. So on Mondays it highlights the data even for yesterday, so all the data for Friday is also getting highlighted.

Comment: Which is first day of week in your country?

Comment: @Shivani Kamthe Please, test the updated code. It should work well for both cases of 'week first day', according to your regionalization. Of course, you should correctly set `firstWeekDay` constant value...